# What is the name of this game by G5 Entertainment?

Tags: game-identification

I played a game long ago and I searched for it and didn't find it.
Can someone identify this game in this photo for it? The game is developed by G5 Entertainment.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Seems it was called [***Dream Catchers: The Beginning HD***](https://www.metacritic.com/game/ios/dream-catchers-the-beginning-hd).  However, it seems to have been removed from App stores.